# Check repeated numbers on a matrix in C

Tags: c, for-loop, matrix, repeat

How can I use repetitions to check if there aren't any repeated numbers on a n x n matrix?

Using two for's two times wouldn't let me check anything that does not share at least a line or a column

Example: (in the most simplified way possible):

```
  int matrix[n][n];
  /*matrix is filled*/
  int current, isEqual;
  for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
      current = matrix[i][j];
      if (current == matrix[i][j+1])
      {
        isEqual=1;
      }
      else
      {
        isEqual=0;
      }
    }
  }
  for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
  {
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
      current = matrix[i][j];
      if (current == matrix[i+1][j])
      {
        isEqual=1;
      }
      else
      {
        isEqual=0;
      }
    }
  }
```

I can't check numbers that don't share lines or columns.

Comment: My problem resides mainly on the logic, I don't understand how should I do it so I can't apply it on the code.

Comment: "*Using two for's two times wouldn't let me check anything that does not share at least a line or a column*". What does that mean? Please show the code. To start off with you can use brute force. Get one element and compare it against all others. Then check the next element against all others and so on.

Comment: I'll edit the question with some code, I think It'll be easier to understand.

Comment: Is there any limit for maximal/minimal numer that can appear in the matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, think in a NxM matrix as if it were an array with length [N*M]. The only difference is how you access the elements (two fors instead of one, for example).
Then, a simple algorithm would be to iterate every element (first index), and for each one, iterate every *other* element (second index) to check if it's the same. It's easier to do with an array; in a matrix it's the same, maybe a bit more verbose and complex. But the algorithm is the same.

As a second phase, after you have implemented the basic algorithm, you can improve its performance starting the second index in the element after the first index. This way, you avoid checking the already seen elements multiple times. This algorithm improvement is slightly harder to do in a matrix, if you iterate it with 2 fors, as it's a bit harder to know what's the "next index" (you have a "compound" index, {i,j}).

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to do this is to insert each number into a data structure that makes it easy to check for duplicates.  This is sort of fun to do in C, and although the following is certainly not super efficient or production ready, it's (IMO) a nice little toy:

```
/* Check if any integer on the input stream is a dup */                            
                                                                                   
#include <stdio.h>                                                                 
#include <stdlib.h>                                                                
                                                                                   
struct node { int data; struct node *child[2]; };                                  
                                                                                   
static struct node *                                                               
new_node(int data)                                                                 
{                                                                                  
        struct node *e = calloc(1, sizeof *e);                                     
        if( e == NULL ){                                                           
                perror("calloc");                                                  
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                
        }                                                                          
        e->data = data;                                                            
        return e;                                                                  
}                                                                                  
                                                                                   
/*                                                                                 
 * Insert a value into the tree. Return 1 if already present.                      
 * Note that this tree needs to be rebalanced.  In a real                          
 * project, we would use existing libraries.  For this toy                         
 * it is not worth the work needed to properly rebalance the                       
 * tree.                                                                           
 */                                                                                
int                                                                                
insert(struct node **table, int data)                                              
{                                                                                  
        struct node *t = *table;                                                   
        if( !t ){  
                *table = new_node(data);                                           
                return 0;
        }                                                              
        if( data == t->data ){                                            
                return 1;                                                  
        }                                                          
        return insert(&t->child[data < t->data], data);                                                                                         
}           

int                                                                                
main(void)                                                                         
{                                                                                  
        int rv, v;                                                                 
        struct node *table = NULL;                                                 
        while( (rv = scanf("%d", &v)) == 1 ){                                     
                if( insert(&table, v) ){                                           
                        fprintf(stderr, "%d is duplicated\n", v);                  
                        return EXIT_FAILURE;                                       
                }                                                                  
        }                                                                          
        if( rv != EOF ){                                                           
                fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n");                                
                return EXIT_FAILURE;                                               
        }                                                                          
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;                                                       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic approach is to loop through the nxn matrix and keeping a list of the numbers in it along with a count of the number of times each number is found in the nxn matrix.

The following is example source code for a 50 x 50 matrix. To extend this to an n x n matrix is fairly straightforward and I leave that as an exercise for you. You may need to do something such as using `malloc()` to create an arbitrary sized matrix. There are posts on that sort of thing.

I also do not specify how the data is put into the matrix in the first place. That is also up to you.

This is to just show a brute force approach for determining if there are duplicates in the matrix.

I've also taken the liberty of assuming the matrix elements are `int` but changing the type to something else should be straightforward. If the matrix elements are something other than a simple data value type such as `int`, `long`, etc. then the function `findAndCount()` will need changing for the equality comparison.

Here are the data structures I'm using.

```
typedef struct {
    int nLength;         // number of list elements in use
    struct {
        int  iNumber;    // number from an element of the nxn matrix
        int  iCount;     // number of times this element was found in the matrix
    } list[50 * 50];
} elementList;

elementList matrixList = {
    0,
    {0, 0}
  };

int matrixThing[50][50];
```

next we need to loop through the matrix and with each element in the matrix to check if it is in the list. If it's not then add it. It does exist then increment the count.

```
for (unsigned short i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    for (unsigned short j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
        findAndCount (matrixThing[i][j], &matrixList);
    }
}
```

And then we need to define our function we use to check matrix values against the list.

```
void findAndCount (int matrixElement, elementList *matrixList)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < matrixList->nLength; i++) {
        if (matrixElement == matrixList->list[i].iNumber) {
            matrixList->list[i].iCount++;
            return;
        }
    }

    // value not found in the list so we add it and set the initial count
    // to one.
    // we can then determine if there are any duplicates by checking the
    // resulting list once we have processed all matrix elements to see
    // if any count is greater than one.
    // the initial check will be to see if the value of nLength is equal
    // to the number of array elements in the matrix, n time n.
    // so a 50 x 50 matrix should result in an nLength of 2500 if each
    // element is unique.
    matrixList->list[matrixList->nLength].iNumber = matrixElement;
    matrixList->list[matrixList->nLength].iCount = 1;
    matrixList->nLength++;
    return;
}
```

**Search algorithms**

The above function, `findAndCheck()`, is a brute force search algorithm that searches through an unsorted list element by element until either the thing being searched for is found or the end of the list is reached.

If the list is sorted then you can use a [binary search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) which is much quicker than a linear search. However you then run into the overhead needed to keep the list sorted using a [sorting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) in order to use a binary search.

If you change the data structure used to store the list of found values to a data structure that maintains values in an ordered sequence, you can also cut down on the overhead of searching though there will also be an overhead of inserting new values into the data structure.

One such data structure is a tree and there are several types and algorithms to build a tree by inserting new items as well as searching a tree. See [search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_tree) which describes several different kinds of trees and searches.

So there is a kind of balancing between the effort to do searching versus the effort to add items to the data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that checks for duplicate values, the way want to do it.
Looping is slow, and we should use a hash set or a tree instead of using loops.
I assume you are not using C++, because the C++ standard library has build-in algorithms and data structures to do it efficiently.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Search the 'array' with the specified 'size' for the value 'key'
   starting from 'offset' and return 1 if the value is found, otherwise 0 */
int find(int key, int* array, int size, int offset) {
    for (int x = offset; x < size; ++x)
        if (key == array[x])
            return 1;
    return 0;
}

/* Print duplicate values in a matrix */
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int matrix[3][3] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6, 2, 8, 2 };
    int size = sizeof(matrix) / sizeof(matrix[0][0]);
    int *ptr = (int*)matrix;
    for (int x = 0; x < size; ++x) {
        /* If we already checked the number, then don't check it again */
        if (find(ptr[x], ptr, x, 0))
            continue;
        /* Check if the number repeats and show it in the console if it does */
        if (find(ptr[x], ptr, size, x + 1))
            printf("%d\n", ptr[x]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When you become better at C, you should find or implement a "hash set" or a "red-black tree", and use that instead.